# Trying to integrate my bookmarklet into a Chrome Extension, but for some reason it doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarklet

I'm trying to integrate my bookmarklet into a Chrome Extension, but for some reason it doesn't work

I tried inserting:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "demo.js"});
```

I tried both into popup.html ; background.html

also i have in the manifest file:

```
"permissions": [   
"tabs",
"http://*/*",
"https://*/*",
"notifications",
"contextMenus"
]
```

my demo.js is supposed to open a popup in which you enter a search phrase and then the wikipedia page opens. ( example taken from here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/23/make-your-own-bookmarklets-with-jquery/ )

I tested the normal bookmarklet code and it works great but now when I try to integrate it with my Chrome extension I can't seem to make it working. When i press the extension icon it just opens a tiny blank extension window.

I tried many other combinations, not just what I said here.
Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple example of `chrome.tabs.executeScript` working at http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red/ if you want to take a look at that.

Compare your manifest.json to the manifest.json there to look for differences in how you set up your browserAction and background page (you shouldn't have a popup page, as far as I can tell from your blog post). Specifically, things you probably want:

```
"background_page": "background.html",
"browser_action": {
    "name": "Search Wikipedia",
    "icons": ["icon.png"]
},
```

Here's how they set up their browserAction to call executeScript() when the extension icon is clicked, which sounds like how you want to do it:

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        null, {code:"document.body.style.background='red !important'"});
});
```

In your case, it'd look more like this (in `background.js` -- see how their `background.html` has `<script src="background.js"></script>`; make sure your `manifest.json` includes `background.html` like they do):

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "demo.js"});
});
```

Comment: thanks I did everything as there ( even though I had looked at that example myself before posting). Still the same problem.

Now with the debug I notice "chrome/ExtensionProcessBindings:83Error during tabs.executeScript: Unknown error."

Comment: sorry, that error appears ONLY WHEN clicking from chrome extensions, which I knew should fails anyway.

When I click on the extension from another tab nothing happens and there's no error in the console.

Comment: btw, now the code is:
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      null, {code: "document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='demo.js'"});
});

Comment: this I modeled after the bookmarklet code:
   <a href="javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='file:///I:/readterms/bookmarklet-demo/demo.js';})();">Test</a>